# Slide mask in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting, masking

I would like to translocate the mask itself that I use in sculpting.

For example, I didn't get the mask quite in the center here:

[image: mask-location]

So I would like to move it the same way you use GG to move vertices in edit mode. Except I dont want to transform the mesh, I'm looking for the equivalent of edge slide, but I would like to slide the mask not the mesh. Is it possible in Blender 3.6?